# Copy table with sdo_geometry data

Tags: oracle, geometry

Is there a direct way to copy a table with `SDO_Geometry` data from one schema to another?

I usually convert the `SDO_GEOMETRY` data into `WKT` then copy it to the other schema then convert it back to `SDO_GEOMETRY`. But I might need to do this more often, so I am wondering if there is a better/more direct way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the best possible method to copy spatial data from one schema to another is exp/imp or expdp/impdp geometry tables.

Comment: yes but I am not a DBA and I think `expdp/imdp` are only available on the server, right? I only have the Oracle client and TOAD IDE. The export options in TOAD doesnt handle SDO_GEOMETRY.

Comment: I just found out that TOAD does provide me with these tools. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, You are right, expdp only writes files on DB Server filesystem. Any way nice to hear that you have found a solution using Toad.